# Sort HashMap into buckets using Java 8 toMap function

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, mapping

I want to group a HashMap by the specific *rank* attached to each key. The keys can either be *rank* 1 or 2. So at the end, a given input hashmap like `<String, Integer>` should be mapped and outputted in this form `<Integer, Set<String>>` - Where the key for the output map is the *rank* and the value is the Set of all strings in the original input map that are of that rank. It would also be nice if the Sets in the output map are ordered in descending of the value in the original map.

Here is how I originally did it and it works, but I would like to use the toMap function, and feel like this method is a bit overkill.

```
private Set<String> sortByValue(Map<String, Long> iMap) {
    //This is where we are going to bucket our stuff
    Map<Integer, Set<String>> rankSort = new HashMap<Integer, Set<String>>() {{
        put(1, new LinkedHashSet<>());
        put(2, new LinkedHashSet<>());
    }};

    //Just populating rankSort with elements from the map
    iMap.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
            .forEachOrdered(e -> rankSort.get(isRank1(e.getKey()) ? 1 : 2).add(e.getKey()));

    return new LinkedHashSet<String>() {{
        addAll(rankSort.get(2));
        addAll(rankSort.get(1));
    }};
}

private boolean isRank1(String val) {
    try {
        return extService.getIt(val).getParent() == null;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is not `toMap` but

```
iMap.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(
        Entry::getValue,
        mapping(Entry::getKey, toSet())));
```

Comment: where in this code would I implement it calling the rank function and bucket it by rank?

Comment: @Ramie, oh, I thought the integers were the ranks.  If that's not the case, then instead of `Entry::getKey` you'd write `e -> isRank1(e.getKey()) ? 1 : 2`.  And you might need some more explicit type annotations.

Comment: I appreciate your reply and ran the code but it seems like this code is sorting them by the integer value for each string (from the input iMap). It should only sort it into 2 different sets, either rank 1 or rank 2. The rank for each string is determined by an external function `isRank1()`.

Comment: @Ramie did you try doing the change I suggested in the comment of replacing `Entry::getKey` with `e -> isRank1(e.getKey()) ? 1 : 2`?

Comment: yeah and that just ended up giving me `<Integer, Set<Integer>>` where the sets in the values contain the ranks (all of them just have a set of 1 element, 1)

Comment: Ahhhhhh, my bad.  Try replacing `Entry::getValue` with that lambda instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110575/discussion-between-ramie-and-louis-wasserman).

Comment: If there are exactly two ranks, you may consider `partitioningBy(e -> isRank1(e.getKey()), …)` instead of `groupingBy`. That’ll create a `Map<Boolean,…>` instead of `Map<Integer,…>`, but has internal optimization potential…